# Gem can be required in IRB but not by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

When I add

```
require 'soundcloud'
```

in Rails and start the server using

```
rails server
```

I get

```
...rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- soundcloud (LoadError)
```

the same yields

```
=> true
```

in IRB.

I installed Ruby, Rails, etc following http://installrails.com/.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use Bundler?

Add to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'soundcloud'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

in the root of your project and it all should work automatically.

Comment: Fantastic. I wasn't aware of Bundler and Gemfile. Been like 4 years since I did anything in Rails. :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, lots of things has changed since Rails 2.3.